# I am trying to extract data from jmeter variables to be stored in a file. Trying to write a regular expression to fit in this code.JOb_id extraction?

Tags: regex, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
String stringToSearch=prev.getResponseDataAsString();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('value="(PR.+?)"');   
Matcher match = p.matcher(stringToSearch);
if (match.find()) {
    def value = match.group(1)
    log.info('------------------')
    log.info(value) // to check in the jmeter log for the extracted data
    vars.put('a', value) 
}
//get path of csv file (creates new one if its not exists)
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Tarik\\Desktop\\example.csv",true); // true to append
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
out.write(vars.get("a"));
out.close();
fileWriter.close();


the data to be extracted looks like this 
Jmeter Variables:

job_id_1:
job_id_2:
....
```

also is it possible to save the extracted output as an xlsx file ?
the job_ids need to be extracted in the file so thatthe file can be used for another api to process it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is extracting the "intersting" values using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and writing them down using [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property, just declare it in *user.properties* file like:

```
sample_variables=your_variable_1,your_variable_2,etc.
```

and once you [run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) the .jtl results file will contain an extra column for each Sample Variable you define via the property.

If you want to have these variable values written in the separate file - go for [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/)

Even if you code is doing what it is supposed to be doing it will fail given even minimal concurrency due to a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) (several threads will be concurrently writing into the file causing data corruption and/or loss)